# Rails: Saving many new objects in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have 2 models:

Video:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :thumbnails
  attr_accessor :search, :saveable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :thumbnails, :allow_destroy => true
en
```

d

Thumbnail:

```
class Thumbnail < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :video

end
```

I am using the YouTubeG gem in order to search for videos.

Each video that is returned by the search has a form in the view:

```
<% form_for :video, :url => videos_path, :html => { :class => :form } do |f| -%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :url, :value => video.unique_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => video.title %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <% if video.thumbnails.present? %>
    <%  f.fields_for :thumbnails, video do |t| %>
      <% video.thumbnails.each do |thumbnail| -%>
        <%=image_tag thumbnail.url %>
        <%=t.text_field :url, :value => thumbnail.url %>
      <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end -%>
```

The f.fields_for :thumbnails produces 
`<input type="hidden" value="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/s8eigkwmMEo/0.jpg" name="video[thumbnails][url]" id="video_thumbnails_url"/>`

which seems to wrong because I want to save all thumbnails for this video.

When I try to save I get

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in VideosController#create

Parameters:

{"commit"=>"Save",
 "video"=>{"name"=>"Karajan - Beethoven Symphony No. 7",
 "url"=>"s8eigkwmMEo",
 "user_id"=>"1",
 "thumbnails"=>{"url"=>"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/s8eigkwmMEo/0.jpg"}}} **< there should be 4 thumbnails**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the correct answer:

**`<%  f.fields_for "thumbnails_attributes[]", Thumbnail.new do` |t| %>**

instead of

```
<%  f.fields_for :thumbnails, video do |t| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use index feature of the `fields_for` helper:

```
  <% video.thumbnails.each do |thumbnail| -%>
  <%  f.fields_for "thumbnail[]", thumbnail do |t| %>  
    <%=image_tag thumbnail.url %>
      <%=t.text_field :url, :value => thumbnail.url %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
```

Look through rails casts edipode trilogy about complex forms: 
[Episode 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1)

Comment: There are new episodes on nested forms for Rails 3: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2